# Access folder using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to access Special folder using LINQ

```
var s1 = (from folder in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).GetDirectories()  
                          select folder).ToList();
```

I'm using this code but not able to retrive data

Comment: which folder you need to access?

Comment: What do you mean with 'not able to retrieve data'. Is there an exception thrown or other error occurrs? Have you tried debuging your code?

Comment: i need to access the folders in the desktop.

Comment: Using LINQ here is completely useless. `from foo in bar select foo` is the same as simply `bar`...

Comment: What is the result of `@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`? Is that the path you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. System.IO and Linq are not best friends since you want to handle exceptions on file level and deferred execution and disk access is difficult
2. Use the `Path` class to create a path, e.g. `Path.Combine(part1, part2, ...)`
3. You don't need the `DirectoryInfo` class if you only want the paths, use the static `Directory` or `File` methods like `Directory.GetDirectories`
4. You get the desktop via `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`
5. You don't need Linq at all:

   ```
   string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
   string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that LINQ is not the best solution for all kinds of problems!

Answer (score 1):

To get all files in the Desktop folder including any files in sub-folders, 
I'd use this code:

```
 string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
  List<FileInfo> s1 = new DirectoryInfo(desktopPath).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

this may help u.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a backslash between username and Desktop:

```
@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
```

But it's easier to use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

That will return the entire path, without hardcoding `c:\users\`.

Answer (score 1):

- Seems you should try `Path.Combine`.
- `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` is not a string, So you must convert it to string.

Sot try this:

```
var desktop = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\", Environment.UserName, Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop.ToString());
var result = (from folder in new DirectoryInfo(desktop).GetDirectories()
                  select folder).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a backslash (`\`) between `Environment.UserName` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`.

e.g.

```
var desktopFolder = string.Format(
    @"C:\Users\{0}\{1}",
    Environment.UserName,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

var s1 = (from folder in new DirectoryInfo(desktopFolder).GetDirectories()
          select folder).ToList();
```